# Assistance evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(2 \sin \theta + \cos \theta\right)d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need help with evaluating the following integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(2 \sin \theta + \cos \theta\right)d\theta$$
I have attempted this but I am not sure how to complete the problem.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

It's an integration interval of length $2\pi$ over a linear combination of $2\pi$-periodic functions with mean $0$, i.e.
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x) dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(x) dx = 0$$
That gives
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} (2\sin \theta + \cos \theta) d\theta= 0$$
without "computation".

---

More generally
$$\int_0^{2\pi k} \alpha \sin\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) 
+ \beta \cos\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) dx = 0 \qquad \forall\ \alpha,\beta,k \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: You mean, the "computation" was hidden in "$2\pi$-periodic functions with mean $0$". (Not really a problem of course, just pointing it out.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin yep, but for $\sin$ and $\cos$ (and more generally $\exp(ik\cdot)$), this is a very common fact. And I think it's more elegant than computing directly, as this even applies to uglier combinations ;-)

Comment: Indeed; nice addition in your edit. +1.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \sin\theta + \frac{\cos\theta}{2} d\theta=\cos\theta-\frac{\sin\theta}{2}$$
So $$ \int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta + \frac{\cos\theta}{2} d\theta=1-1-0+0=0$$

Comment: Someone edited your question to use `\sin` and `\cos`, which render as $\sin$ and $\cos$ (built-in shorthands looking better than $sin$ and $cos$). For further information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).